# Ordinal Encoding: How can I encode values that meet a specific criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A column in the data frame is "price". I would like to categorise the prices into three groups: cheap, medium and expensive. How can I replace values with a rank based on the condition that they meet, where 1 = cheap, 2 = medium and 3 = expensive?

```
cheap = (df["price"] <= 932) 
medium = (df["price"] > 932) & (df["price"] <= 2175) 
expensive  = (df["price"] > 2175)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best way to do it, but you could try something like this:

```
df.loc[df["price"] <= 932, "price_category"] = 1
df.loc[(df["price"] > 932) & (df["price"] <= 2175), "price_category"] = 2
df.loc[df["price"] > 2175, "price_category"] = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an anonymous function if the dataset is big enough, otherwise the method of the author below is good for small ones:

```
anonymous = lambda price: 'cheap' if price <= 932 else 'medium' if (price > 932 and x <= 2175) else 'expensive' if price > 2175 else "Not Categorized"

df[price_column] = df[price_column].apply(anonymous)
```